# Perl - split html code by "table" tag and its contents

Tags: html, regex, perl, split

I'm trying to split a chunck of html code by the "table" tag and its contents.

So, I tried

```
my $html = 'aaa<table>test</table>bbb<table>test2</table>ccc';
my @values = split(/<table*.*\/table>/, $html);
```

After this, I want the @values array to look like this: 
`array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc')`.
But it returns this array: 
`array('aaa', 'ccc')`.
Can anyone tell me how I can specify to the split function that each table should be parsed separately?

Thank you!

Comment: When parsing HTML, use a HTML parser. Perl has a good one, IIRC.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex is greedy, change it to `/<table.*?\/table>/` and it will do what you want.  But you should really look into a proper HTML parser if you are going to be doing any serious work.  A search of [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org) should find one that is suited to your needs.

Comment: And in case it hasn't been linked enough yet, [here's why](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Answer (score 3):

Your regex `.*` is greedy, therefore chewing its way to the last part of the string. Change it to `.*?` and it should work better.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `?` to specify non-greedy wild-card char slurping, i.e.

```
my @values = split(/<table*.*?\/table>/, $html);
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe using HTML parser is a bit overkill for your example, but it will pay off later when your example grows. Solution using [HTML::TreeBuilder](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder):

```
use HTML::TreeBuilder;
use Data::Dump qw(dd);

my $html = 'aaa<table>test</table>bbb<table>test2</table>ccc';
my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content($html);

# remove all <table>....</table>
$_->delete for $tree->find('table');

dd($tree->guts);        # ("aaa", "bbb", "ccc")
```